Why is My Python Solution For Trapped Rain Problem so slow?
I have been working on the Leetcode version of the Trapped Rain Problem (See below). My solution passes almost all of the test cases, but I get a "Time Limit Exceeded" failure on test 318, which is just a very long input. I'm a noob, so can someone tell me what part of my solution has the biggest time cost? My code is after the problem description.
Given n non-negative integers representing an elevation map where the width of each bar is 1, compute how much water it can trap after raining.
Example 1:

Input: height = [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]
Output: 6
Explanation: The above elevation map (black section) is represented by array [0,1,0,2,1,0,1,3,2,1,2,1]. In this case, 6 units of rain water (blue section) are being trapped.
Example 2:
Input: height = [4,2,0,3,2,5]
Output: 9
Constraints:
n == height.length
1 <= n <= 2 * 104
0 <= height[i] <= 105

Code:
class Solution(object):
    def trap(self, height):
        """
        :type height: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        volume = 0
        ceiling = 0
        for i in height:
            if i > ceiling:
                ceiling = i

        while ceiling > 0:
            list_of_peaks = []
            for i in range(0,len(height)):
                if height[i] >= ceiling:
                    list_of_peaks.append(i)
            for elem in range(0,len(list_of_peaks)):
                try:
                    volume = volume + (list_of_peaks[elem+1]-list_of_peaks[elem]-1)
                except:
                    break
            ceiling -= 1
        return volume

I have tried to identify what part of my solution is inefficient, but I am not experienced enough to identify what needs to be improved.

why the try except inside the loop?

Surely the nested loops are a problem. See if you can come up with a single-pass solution where you collect "water" after the latest local maximum, or perhaps a two-pass solution where you identify the valleys and then loop over those.

This is because the time complexity of your code is O(nm), where n is the number of elements in height, and m is the maximum value in height. In this case, n*m can reach at most 2*10^4*10^5
You should consider other algorithm, such as DP.
class Solution:
def trap(self, height: List[int]) -> int:
    if not height:
        return 0
    
    n = len(height)
    leftMax = [height[0]] + [0] * (n - 1)
    for i in range(1, n):
        leftMax[i] = max(leftMax[i - 1], height[i])

    rightMax = [0] * (n - 1) + [height[n - 1]]
    for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
        rightMax[i] = max(rightMax[i + 1], height[i])

    ans = sum(min(leftMax[i], rightMax[i]) - height[i] for i in range(n))
    return ans


Let's break down your algorithm into its time complexity
        for i in height:
            if i > ceiling:
                ceiling = i

You're trying to find the highest height. This is O(n) time complexity. By the way in Python you can just do ceiling = max(height).
        while ceiling > 0:
            list_of_peaks = []
            for i in range(0,len(height)):
                if height[i] >= ceiling:
                    list_of_peaks.append(i)
            for elem in range(0,len(list_of_peaks)):
                try:
                    volume = volume + (list_of_peaks[elem+1]-list_of_peaks[elem]-1)
                except:
                    break
            ceiling -= 1


Here your while loop runs ceiling number of times (because you are decrementing ceiling by 1 each time). Within each iteration of the while loop, you try to find all bars which are at least as high as the current ceiling considered. So the time complexity comes to O(ceiling * n). This is where your algorithm gets really slow.
Think of an input like this where you have one very tall bar.
   x
   x
   x
   x
   x
   x  x
   xx x
   xx xx
x xxxxxxx


Your while loop is running as many times as the tallest bar which is completely unnecessary.
The problem can instead be solved like this in O(n) time.
class Solution:
    def trap(self, heights: list[int]) -> int:
        if not heights or len(heights) <= 2:
            return 0
        
        n = len(heights)
        
        # left_max[i] gives you the index of the tallest bar to the left of  index i
        left_max = [0] * n
        # right_max[i] gives you the index of the tallest bar to the right of  index i
        right_max = [0] * n
        
        # Fill left_max array
        left_max[0] = heights[0]
        for i in range(1, n):
            left_max[i] = max(left_max[i - 1], heights[i])
        
        # Fill right_max array
        right_max[n - 1] = heights[n - 1]
        for i in range(n - 2, -1, -1):
            right_max[i] = max(right_max[i + 1], heights[i])
        
        # Calculate the trapped water at each column
        volume = 0
        for i in range(n):
            volume += max(min(left_max[i], right_max[i]) - heights[i], 0)
            # Let us analyse the above line:
            #
            # min(left_max[i], right_max[i]) because, at each index,
            # the volume of water trapped is limited by
            # the shorter of the tallest bars on the left and right.
            #
            # - heights[i] because this column of water will stand
            # on the current bar.
            #
            # max(..., 0) because if there is no bar taller than the 
            # current bar on the left and right, then it would be 0.
        
        return volume

